# Is there a way to mount a disk directly to a specific folder?

Tags: mount, disk-volume

Using Mac OS X 10.4

I made a script a while ago for my Linux box in order to take archived data off of 300 floppies that automated the process. I would make an image of the floppy and copy the files directly off of the floppy. I managed to install Xcode on the machine (in order to install `ddrescue`)

The thing is on a Linux box I mounted each floppy to `/media/floppy` and unmounted it to `ddrescue` it and copied it directly to a usb drive.

I'm trying to port my script to the Mac, and it seems that its default behavior is to automatically mount each zip floppy to the `/Volumes` folder, which is fine, except it uses the volume's name as its mount point folder name. So if a floppy's volume name is: *"Jimmy Bo Bobs"* it will mount to `/media/Jimmy /Bo /Bobs`.

So my question is I need to get the volume name either consistent to one name, or adaptable to the volume's name.

So my initial question is can I some how mount a drive to a specific folder, Like I would normally do in linux?

```
 #Linux
 mount /dev/sd1 /media/floppy
 #Mac
 diskutil mount /dev/disk1s1 /media/floppy #Doesn't work
```

If it's not possible, is there an easy way to extract the volume's name so that I can then link the script like this?

```
 Volumename=Jimmy Bo Bobs
 do stuff to /Volume/$Volumename
```

I'm guessing if it's not possible I'll have to grep the `mount` command to the `/dev/` pointer and then somehow parse that string which is what I want to avoid since it would require even more research.

Comment: Have You checked `[-mountPoint path]` option for `diskutil` ?

Comment: The help file and man don't make a mention of it, will look through google...

Comment: here's my `man`: 
"mount [readOnly] [-mountPoint path] device
                Mount a single volume.  If readOnly is specified, then the file system is mounted read-only, even if the volume's underlying file system and/or device and/or media supports
                writing; even the super-user may not write to it; this is the same as the rdonly option to mount (8).  If a -mountPoint is specified, then that path, rather than the stan-
                dard path of /Volumes/VolumeName, will be used as the view into the volume file content; a directory at that path must already exist."

Comment: Hmmm... I see the man online, and your man, and they don't match mine. I tried both sudo diskutil mount /dev/disk2s4 -mountPoint /Volumes/test and sudo diskutil mount -mountPoint /Volumes/test /dev/disk2s4 ... I suspect 10.4 doesn't have the -mountPoint feature.

Comment: Does `/Volumes/test` exist before running this command?

Comment: Yep, it does, with the -mountPoint as the first argument it outputs "Disk Utility Tool Usage: ...." when it's the second argument it mounts the volume under it's volume name, using my example above /Volume/JimmyBobs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can mount a drive to a specific folder. The caveat is that the user who is mounting the volume must be the mount-point owner. You do NOT need to be root or use sudo to mount a disk.

The first thing is to identify your raw device. `diskutil list` will do that nicely.

For example, if I have a FAT32 USB stick that I want to mount in my home dir, I list my devices and see that my raw device is `/dev/disk5s1`. As a normal user, I can mount it in my home directory by:

```
mkdir ~/mount
mount -r -t msdos /dev/disk5s1 ~/mount
```

If you then `cd ~/mount ; ls`, you'll see the contents of the USB stick.

In this example, I mounted it *read-only*, but you can mount your device any way you like.

When you're done with the device, don't forget to unmount it, e.g.:

```
diskutil unmount ~/mount
```

Comment: SUCCESS!!! mount -t hfs /dev/disk1s4 ~/mountpoint/

Comment: any way for this to happen automatically whenever I connect the same drive?

Comment: @rmp251, I don't think there's any way to automate this. That said, you may be able to create a script that you could run that would mount the drive with nothing more than a double-click. Assuming that you are mounting only one drive regularly, it should get the same device name every time you mount it.

Comment: @rmp251 After you've mounted volumes, you can automate the mounts at login by dragging the mounted volumes into your Login Items within the Users & Groups / Accounts panel in System Preferences.

Answer (score 5):

This is described in comments, but it ought to be put into an answer.  In MacOS 10.11.6 (and probably later versions), you can use

```
diskutil mount -mountPoint ~/mount /dev/disk5s1
```

Unlike using `mount`, it's not necessary to specify the filesystem type, at least for `hfs` type disks (all that I have tried).

I found that I had to `sudo` to root to do this either using `mount` as in @TraneFranks' answer, or with `diskutil mount` as above, even though I own the mount point directory.  I don't understand why `sudo` is needed.  Using `diskutil mount` without `-mountPoint`, the disk is mounted in a default location in /Volumes, and I don't need to be root.  However, I recommend keeping in mind that `sudo` might be needed, because the error message without it is mysterious.

Answer (score 1):

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is the name of the Drive as you'd see it in the finder
volname=<Volume Name>

# Mount point you want to mount it to.
mountPoint=/Users/<username>/extra


function remount() {
  sudo diskutil unmount "$vol"
  sudo diskutil mount -mountpoint "$mountPoint" "$vol"
  exit 0
}
vol=$(diskutil list | grep "$volname" | awk '{print $7}')
mount | grep "$vol" | grep "/Volumes/$volname" > /dev/null && remount
```

What I do is just add a cron that runs every minute. There is very little system resources for when there isn't anything to do so just run it every minute.  If it finds it, it re-maps it to the proper location.

```
* * * * * <location of script> > /dev/null 2>&1
```