# How can I mount a local USB-connected to an alternate mount point?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, mount, automount

I am running SyncThing to keep a hard-drive at home in sync with one at my office.  Is there a way to mount both drives at the same mount point?  I'd like to detect when a drive is plugged in, and mount it at a single known mount point instead of /Volumes/[Disk Name].

This is so apps like Logic Studio, which reference media files (probably by path), can find the same media files at the same directory path, no matter which location I am at.  Currently, they lose the file when I switch locations and I have to go manually 'find' the new path for the app.

Thanks for any insights you could provide.

Comment: Naming both drives with the same name wouldn't be enough? They'd be mounted at /Volumes/same_name!

Comment: @frizlab  Thanks.  That is a good idea.  Will volume UUIDs being different matter?

Comment: not for the mounting points, and thus not for the paths of the files in the drive :) About Logic Studio and other Media applications, I don't know specifically how they handle linking the files, but I guess they primarily trust the paths.

Comment: My experience has been that they resolve all paths to absolute, real pathnames, which prevents the use of softlinks, or aliases.  I like your answer for its apparent ease of implementation, but the purist in me still wonders is it possible to do something different from what Apple prescribes.  It'd be nice, but not essential, to still be able to see my drives for what they are (ie with their own unique names), but still be able to use them interchangeably.  All of that said, I think I'll give your solution a try.  I'm not 100% sure that Syncthing will handle it, but I think it will.

Comment: There are answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/147697/44485).